# How can I deal with vertex precision errors between terrain chunks?

Tags: opengl, terrain, vertex, floating-point, precision

I am using OpenGL to render the following scene, using vertex data from one of the map files of a popular MMORPG. The data is chunked and the pictured scene is made up of 256 (16x16) chunks.

However between the chunks I am seeing what I believe to be glitches due to the float precision. Yet I am not doing any large translations and rendering very close to the origin, should I be seeing this problem? The glitches very noticeable as you fly over the scene with it flickering different points along the chunk edges.

I was wondering if I was overlooking something simple or there are tricks other games use to mask this problem. I guess the source data could be the reason for this problem but I am not aware of it happening in the original game.

[image: Overview]
[image: Zoomed]

View screenshots in a new window to see the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loss of precision happens due to the rotation in your **combined** view-model or projection-view-model` matrix.

You will need to use a vertex shader (if not already using one) and apply the model matrix (or a plain translation in your case since those are axis-aligned chunks) before applying the view-projection **separately**:

```
uniform vec2 chunk_offset;

...

vec4 temp = vec4(chunk_vertex.xy + chunk_offset, chunk_vertex.z, 1) * projection_view_matrix;
```

The isue is because the +/- chunk offset gets **rotated first** and put into the translation part of the combined projection-view-model matrix causing an initial precision loss before being added to the also-rotated vertex coordinates (another precision loss).

Separating the operations avoid this loss of precision and your `+0.5 vertex` will match your `-0.5 vertex` + `1.0 chunk offset` perfectly giving the exact same value which will then be rotated with both hitting the same loss of precision in the projection-view matrix.